# Redirect to subdirectory from multiple domain

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns, subdirectory

I have multiple domain that point to the same server. Then i need to separate it to different directory. how to make it in htaccess or other way.

Here an example.

```
domain1.com show 1.2.3.4/abc
domain2.com show 1.2.3.4/def
domain3.com show 1.2.3.4/ghi
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use these type of rules in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^abc/ /abc%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^def/ /def%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain3\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^ghi/ /ghi%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: it not working then i add "RewriteEngine On" at top and it working. is it correct?

Comment: Sorry I missed that line, edited now. Yes that line is needed.

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.